# VbScript REGEX pattern

Tags: vbscript

I'm building a vbscript and I m using a Regexp Object.
I need help to create a regex pattern that finds the following words/chars

```
Advanced
Standard
Enterprise
Edition
(R)
®
@
```

The script :

```
Set objRegExp = New Regexp
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = ""
objRegExp.Replace(myVar, "")
```

What Should I have in

```
objRegExp.Pattern = ""
```

Comment: Formatting to improve readability. Poster needs to edit to include what they've tried in the way of regular expressions that haven't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the encoding of code and data is compatible:

Option Explicit

```
Dim s : s = "1Advanced2Standard3Enterprise4Edition5(R)6®7@8,9"
Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Global = True
r.Pattern = "Advanced|Standard|Enterprise|Edition|\(R\)|®|@|,"
WScript.Echo r.Replace(s, "")
```

output:

```
cscript 38061990.vbs
123456789
```

**Update wrt comment:**

Based on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_trademark_symbol):

```
Option Explicit

Dim csCircledR : csCircledR = ChrW(&H00AE)
Dim s : s = "1Advanced2Standard3Enterprise4Edition5(R)6" & csCircledR & "7@8,9"
Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
r.Global = True
r.Pattern = "Advanced|Standard|Enterprise|Edition|\(R\)|" & csCircledR & "|@|,"
WScript.Echo s
WScript.Echo r.Replace(s, "")
```

output:

```
cscript 38061990.vbs
1Advanced2Standard3Enterprise4Edition5(R)6®7@8,9
123456789
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, is it possible to include Chr(Code) inse the pattern?